# Variable not passing into anther class Java

Tags: java

got a strange one, i have a variable `t` i use it in one class, it changes, (e.g. 1 becomes 5) and then i call it from another class to use in that class, problem is t is always 0 when it is passed, what am i doing wrong

here is t in the class where it is edited

```
public int t = 1; //defualt value for amount of seconds in the future the job should wait untill sent

    public int getT() {
        return (t);
    }

    public void setT(int t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
```

and this is the class that i am using that calls t from the above class to use:

```
public class DealyTillPrint {

    public int t;

    public String CompletefileName;
    private String printerindx;
    private static int s;
    private static int x;
    public static int SecondsTillRelase;

    public void countDown() {
        System.out.println("Countdown called");
        s = 1; // interval 
        t = (t * 60); // number of seconds
        System.out.println("t is : " + t);
        while (t > 0) {
            System.out.println("Printing in : " + t);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(s * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            t--;
        }
```

and here is where i set `t` using a spinner

```
<p:spinner min="1" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}"  size ="1">
                    <p:ajax update="NewTime"/>
                </p:spinner>
```

How can i call t where the value is passed that is not zero

Comment: You haven't shown any code where `setT` or `getT` are called.

Comment: Not all variables called `t` across classes are the same...

Comment: you simply created a new variable named t in your DealyTillPrint class, you are not using the `t` from other class

Comment: No, you're not using anything that "calls t from the above class". You have declared and are using `t` in your second class.

Comment: Ok thanks, how can i use t from the other class ? have i done something very wrong here ? sorry newbie !

Comment: Need to access it using an instance of your other class where t is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DealyTillPrint` you declare `public int t;`  That `t` is different than the `t` you declare in the first code sample.  Since you give it no value, it's default value of 0 is assigned.  You are doing nothing to share `t` in the first sample with `t` in the second sample.

Change `t = (t * 60); // number of seconds` to `t = (printerSettings.getT() * 60);`

Comment: Thank i now understand that :), how do i share t with from the first code segment to the second

Comment: updated to answer your question

Comment: Thanks i have tried that and i get `non-static method getT() can not be referenced from a static context`

Comment: I would suggest you go through some of the java tutorials. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `printerSettings` object from web page into your `DealyTillPrint` object. I can't tell you how to do that looking at the code you've submitted.